# C# Automapper nested ViewModel

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a problem with mapping of Nested ViewModel into Parent ViewModel:
These are my entities:

```
 public class Patient : DeletableEntity
{
    public int? PersonalDataId { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonalData PersonalData { get; set; }
}

 public class PersonalData : DeletableEntity
{
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string EGN { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 200)]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    ...
    }
```

and these are ViewModels:

```
 public class PatientModel : IMapFrom<Patient>, IHaveCustomMappings
{

    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public PersonalDataModel PersonalDataModel { get; set; }
}

 public class PersonalDataModel : IMapFrom<PersonalData>, IHaveCustomMappings
{
    [StringLength(10)]
    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_EGN", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string EGN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_DateOfBirth", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 200)]
    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_Age", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_Gender", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PersonalDataModel_FirstNameRequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_SecondName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PersonalDataModel_LastNameRequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "PersonalData_LastName", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
   ...
   }
```

This is the configuration for PersonalDataModel:

```
   configuration.CreateMap<PersonalDataModel, Address>();
        configuration.CreateMap<PersonalDataModel, Telephone>();
        configuration.CreateMap<PersonalDataModel, PersonalData>()
           .ForMember(p => p.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model))
           .ForMember(p => p.Telephone, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model))
           .ForMember(p => p.MobileTelephone, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => new Telephone { Number = model.MobileTelephoneNumber }))
           .ForMember(p => p.Fax, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => new Telephone {Number = model.FaxNumber }))
           .ReverseMap();
```

But I don't know how tо write the configuration for PatientModel.